# Stop/Play on hover jquery reel

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-reel

Hi I'm a relatively new to using jquery reel. I'd like to find out how to Stop and Play when you hover over jquery reel http://test.vostrel.cz/jquery.reel/docs/jquery.reel.html. I see there is a stop, start and pause event, but I'm not sure how to activate it on hover.

Thanks!

```
<img id="image360" src='1.jpg' width="610" height="480" />

<script>
$(function(){ 

//pause on hover (This does not work although hover is registered)
        $('#image360').hover(function() {

        ('#image360').pause();
},

function() {
        ('#image360').play();
});

//360 settings

        $('#image360').reel({
        indicator:   5,
        cw:          true,
        frame:       36,
        speed:       -0.3,
        velocity:    2,
        brake:       .2,
        images:      'cmopen/#.jpg' 
        });

        });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show some code? What have you already tried? See also: http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks appreciate the help, updated with code.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem and solved it with two JS functions :

```
function reel_pause() {
    $('#your_reel_id').trigger("stop"); //stoppe le défilement automatique.
}
function reel_play() {
    if ($('#your_reel_id').data("backwards")) { //teste le sens de défilement.
        $('#your_reel_id').trigger('play'); //relance le défilement à la même frame où on l'a arrêté. Attention, il relance dans son sens naturel (droite à gauche).
        $('#your_reel_id').data("backwards", true) //inverse le sens de défilement
    } else {
        $('#your_reel_id').trigger('play'); //si le sens où l'on a arrêté le défilement est le sens naturel, on n'a pas besoin d'inverser comme au dessus.
    }
}
```

**That is only important if you dont want your reel to loop:**
The "if" statement, if you dont speak french, is used to check the direction when the reel is playing.

```
$('#your_reel_id').data("backwards")
$('#your_reel_id').data("backwards", true)
```

The first one returns true or false. False-> playing from right to left.
The second changes the natural direction -> left to right.
I did this because when you play the reel, it plays in the natural direction. Even if you stopped it when it was playing the other way.

The html looks like this :

```
<div id="container" onmouseover="reel_pause()" onmouseout="reel_play()">
    <img src="../Images/image.jpg" id="your_reel_id" width="900" height="500" />
</div>
```

I have it wrapped in a div cause i use links inside the reel. If you hover a link, it is as if you mouseout the reel and it starts playing again.
Hope it helps!

I am by no mean a JS specialist so if anyone has a better way to do it, please post it!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use methods: pause(), play().

```
$(<your_element>).hover(function() {
    <your_reel>.pause();
},function() {
    <your_reel>.play();
});
```